# Como exibir conteúdos de outra pagina dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Gostaria de poder exibir diversos conteúdos (de outras páginas) numa única página por cada clique num link ou botão que o usuário der. Sei que uma das soluções seria usar o AJAX, mas o problema é que quando dou um *refresh*, o conteúdo que esta visível no momento some e volta o da página principal, o que eu gostaria é permanecer na mesma página com o mesmo conteúdo antes do *refresh*.

O código Javascript que uso é este:

```
$.ajax({
    url : './pagina.php',
    type : 'POST',
  cache: false,
    data : 'dado=' + dado,
    beforeSend: function () {},
    complete: function () {},       
    success: function(data){
       $('#showInfo').html(data); //      $('# showInfo').show();
    },
    error: function(){
       // comandos a serem executados caso Houver algum 
    });
```

Um outro que também tenho usado é:

```
  $.get("pautas.php?acao=1", function( data ) {
    $('#content').html(data);
  });
```

Alguém pode por favor, me dar uma dica???

Answer (score 0):

Cada clique que o usuário der adicione na url um hash. Assim você terá um controle das páginas que aquele usuário já passou e saberá quantas páginas precisa carregar.

```
var page = 0;

$('button.next').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = page+=1;
});
```

Quando a página for carregada você verifica se tem hash, se tiver você tera que carregar a quantidade de informações que aquele hash representar. Se cada página voce carrega 10 dados e o o usuario deu reload no #3 você precisa imprimir com o ajax 30 resultados.

Para pegar o hash da url basta utilizar

```
window.location.hash
```